# A view set as a transparent application overlay blocks back button and keyboard on Oreo when interacting with the window behind the view

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have set up a view that overlays a transparent red filter across the device, which allows touch events to pass though. This works fine on api level 21-25 but with 26 the keyboard does not come up when clicking a text field in any app and the back buttons does not respond when pressed, all other touch events appear to pass fine.

```
wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    topView = new View(this);
    topView.setAlpha(0.3f);
    topView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams topParams;

    //Need to use a swap from TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY to TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY when api => 26
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        topParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    }else{
        topParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    }


    wm.addView(topView, topParams);
```

This is how I set up the view, is there some flag I can set to fix the keyboard and back button issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration worked for me, try to play with flags below (special attention to `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`):

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT
)
```

Hope it helps